# Is it safe to leave the GND from an antenna jack unconnected from an active antenna amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, rf, signal, antenna

I need help with trying to use properly [this circuit](https://www.learningelectronics.net/VA3AVR/circ/activant.html), the original idea came from the late Tony Van Roon who designed it.

According to the article it seems that the logic behind it is that the dim signal goes to the FET amplifier thus improving the signal. Of course I understand that there can arise some considerations as there can be noise nearby from EM fields and so on. But that is not my question.

My question is **can you use this circuit in a telescopic antenna such as receivers which lack from a jack as indicated in the circuit?. And if so which ends to connect where?.** I intend to use this to improve the reception in my SG-622 shortwave radio but my unit does not have a jack.

Since I don't have access to the GND of the receiver I can use an aligator clip to connect the telescopic antenna of the receiver to the output jack on J1 which is tied to the output of the 470 pF capacitor C2.

However I am not sure if it would be safe to leave the GND from J1 unplugged?. Will it have the same results?. Will it improve the signal?.

Some guy used this for a transistor radio and the [video can be seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zMNFy8HCFE). Near the end of the video he shows how he had used it but the video doesn't show very clear where did he connected the GND on the receiver. In the comments this person indicates that he connected the output from C2 to the tunning capacitor on the transistor radio and it can be heard that the reception improved. However some person in the comments indicated that such circuit cannot be used in whip or telescopic antennas on radios as most of these are for FM and AM uses another antenna. This has left me confused.

Another guy [seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6K8UyayH6YM) used the same circuit for his Baofeng uv-3r receiver which it does come with a jack which it does have access to GND on the receiver. On the same video it can be seen around second 37 that the GND from J1 is left unconnected when used in a telescopic antenna such as in those portable SW receivers. The video doesn't seem to show very "much improverment" and it seems it was just a modest boost. Thus, will leave unconnected the GND make any effect?. Can someone help me here?. I'm really in doubt if should it be safe and okay to leave that unconnected?.

Can someone help me to address these doubts?.

Comment: It’s sensitive to stray lightning E field either way without a a balun and a gnd plane adds 3dB

Comment: I think you'd get better results by tying ground to chassis ground, even if that means opening the unit to create a chassis tie point. The next best thing would be Earth ground, such as from the unit (if using a three-prong plug) etc. It likely would not do much without it. 9V is safe to touch while operating. You may find experimentation is needed to find a good L value for your desired frequencies.